Opencsv convertion bean enums to csv
I would like to write a csv file from a bean with enums. My bean contains:
@NotNull(message = "userRole should not be blank")
private UserRole userRole;

UserRole class:
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum UserRole {
    STUDENT("student"),
    TEACHER("teacher");

    private final String value;
}

Building csv file looks like that:
private <T extends CsvBean> String writeCsvFromBean(Path ddir, String fileName, List<T> obj) throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
    String filePath = ddir.resolve(fileName).toString();
    try (Writer writer  = new FileWriter(filePath)) {
        StatefulBeanToCsv<T> sbc = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<T>(writer)
        .withSeparator(ICSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
        .build();

        sbc.write(obj);
    }
    return filePath;
}

In the resulted csv file I can see the enum values listed as STUDENT/TEACHER (capital letters) instead of enum's valueOf results student/teacher. How to force opencsv to generate csv based on enum valueOf?
BR

By default enum conversion is using name() of the enum, referring to ConverterEnum.
You may override this conversion using CsvCustomBindByName and create a custom converter.
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvCustomBindByName;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class CsvBean {
    @CsvCustomBindByName(converter = UserRoleConverter.class)
    private UserRole userRole;
}

import com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class UserRoleConverter extends AbstractBeanField<UserRole, String> {
    // for reading back from csv to bean
    @Override
    protected Object convert(String value) {
        return Arrays.stream(UserRole.values())
                .filter(userRole -> userRole.getValue().equals(value))
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected String convertToWrite(Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return ((UserRole) value).getValue();
    }
}


Thanks! Works great. Is this possible to have this class generic? In case there are several enums like UserRole to include?

You can create an interface, e.g. StringValuedEnum which contains getValue method, and let your enum classes implement that interface. Then create a StringValuedEnumConverter. This should work for writing to csv, but need more work for reading from csv.
